# Concatenate chararray with bag of tuples in Apache Pig

Tags: casting, apache-pig, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two columns of a table, one of which is a `string` (`charray`) and the other one is a bag of tuples:

```
t1 = GROUP K by domain; 
t2 = FOREACH t1 GENERATE CONCAT(t1.group, '\t', t1.K);
```

However, I am getting an error:

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.CONCAT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Don't know what cast to use. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

[CONCAT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#concat) take two expressions of the same type.In your PIG statement you have 3 expressions.You will need another CONCAT.For casting,prefix the datatype (chararray) before the field.Also,you will have to escape the '\'.

```
t2 = FOREACH t1 GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT((chararray)t1.group,'\\t'),(chararray)t1.K);
```

Answer (score 0):

[CONCAT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#concat) function to concatenate two expressions. The result values of the two expressions must have identical types.

Ultimately **CONCAT** is a **Java function** which supports arguments of identical type. You can achieve the same by passing same type of expressions.